# How do I get the truststore properties right in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi, tls1.2

I'm trying to set up Apache NiFi in a Docker container using HTTPS. I used the TLS Toolkit to generate a keystore and truststore:

```
sudo /opt/nifi-toolkit-1.21.0/bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone \
  --days 365 --hostnames my.fqdn.com --trustStorePassword myPassword \
  --keyStorePassword myPassword -C 'CN=admin,OU=NiFi'
```

That also generates a nifi.properties file. I started up a NiFi container based on the example provided on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi):

```
sudo docker run --name nifi   -v /opt/certs:/opt/certs -p 8443:8443 \
  -e AUTH=tls -e KEYSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/nifi-2023-07/my.fqdn.com/keystore.jks \
  -e KEYSTORE_TYPE=JKS -e KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=myPassword \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/nifi-2023-07/my.fqdn.com/truststore.jks \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=myPassword -e TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=JKS\
  -e INITIAL_ADMIN_IDENTITY='CN=admin,OU=NiFi' \
  -d apache/nifi:1.21.0
```

There are differences between the nifi.properties file generated by `docker run` and the one generated by `tls-toolkit`. I made a couple adjustments to the `tls-toolkit` one (point to the correct port, change the path for `nifi.security.keystore` and `nifi.security.keystore`), then copied the `tls-toolkit`-generated nifi.propertes into the Docker container.

With either version of the file, I get an error:

```
2023-07-11 14:50:47,315 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory Some truststore properties are populated (/opt/certs/nifi-2023-07/nifi.4vservices.com/truststore.jks, ********, JKS) but not valid
2023-07-11 14:50:47,316 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid nifi.web.https configuration in nifi.properties
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.<init>(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:89)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.configureConnectors(JettyServer.java:738)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.init(JettyServer.java:207)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.initialize(JettyServer.java:1074)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:164)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:83)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:332)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.security.util.TlsException: The truststore properties are not valid
        at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.getTrustManagers(SslContextFactory.java:181)
        at org.apache.nifi.security.util.SslContextFactory.createSslContext(SslContextFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.connector.FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.<init>(FrameworkServerConnectorFactory.java:86)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
2023-07-11 14:50:47,321 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown started
2023-07-11 14:50:47,322 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown completed
```

The truststore properties:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it nifi grep truststore /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties
nifi.security.truststore=/opt/certs/nifi-2023-07/my.fqdn.com/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=JKS
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=myPassword
nifi.security.user.oidc.truststore.strategy=JDK
nifi.security.user.saml.http.client.truststore.strategy=JDK
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststore=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststoreType=
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststorePasswd=
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? If not, is there a way to get a more detailed error message?